# Button rounded border on hover not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a button and I used `animation` to show borders when hovering over that button. But borders work perfectly on top and bottom but on left and right there are not showing properly.

I want borders to be rounded as here:

[image]

My Outcome:

[image]

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #fff;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #fff;
}

button:hover::before,
button:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover span::before,
button:hover span::after {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-3::after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.btn-3 span::after {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-3::before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.btn-3 span::before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.btn-3:hover::after {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn-3:hover span::after {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.btn-3:hover::before {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.btn-3:hover span::before {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<button (click)="openDialog()" 
        class="extended-fab-button btn-3" 
        mat-fab color="primary">
  <span class="extended-fab-button__text">Test File</span>
</button>
```

Comment: you over complicating the issue. Start clean with your CSS and only make a style for your button when not hovering and then a style when hovering. No before or after or anything else. Then add a transition to those 2 selectors.

Comment: What is the intent of your pseudo-elements? Years ago we'd use them for gloss effects or whatever. What's your plan here?

Comment: Obviously your demo doesn't work as you describe, and you have a bunch of CSS for a class that's not in your markup. Please revise to be more clear what you're after.

Comment: the issue is with the pseudo-elements. you cant set a border-radius there as f.e. the bottom line has a height of 2px and a width of 100%. you can't set a border-radius here / it is not doing the thing you want. i've seen similar things with an svg, that is animated -> drawing the ring.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your `border-radius: 100px;` rule, then your button will have the shape you described as desirable in your question.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #fff;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #fff;
}

button:hover::before,
button:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover span::before,
button:hover span::after {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-3::after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.btn-3 span::after {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn-3::before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.btn-3 span::before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.btn-3:hover::after {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.btn-3:hover span::after {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.btn-3:hover::before {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.btn-3:hover span::before {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<button (click)="openDialog()" 
        class="extended-fab-button btn-3" 
        mat-fab color="primary">
  <span class="extended-fab-button__text">Test File</span>
</button>
```